# Loading Products Filtered by Category

Tags: product, category, collection, category-products

This snippet works fine except that it returns a different set of product collection, mainly due to `is anchor` attribute:

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(1371);
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addCategoryFilter($category);
```

The snippet above returns the complete products including the child category products. However, when running through cron, it returns only a small amount of items. I could simulate what the cron is getting by defining:

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
```

I want to get the collection that includes the sub category products. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try This code

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('memory_limit', '600M');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 1800);
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin'); 
    $_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(48)
    ->getProductCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
     ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);
     foreach($_productCollection as $product){
         var_dump($product->getName());

     }

?>
```